# Adding Custom Coordinate System to FME?

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

How do I add a custom coordinate system to FME?

I need to transform my data to EPSG 3765 which is not in Coordinate System Gallery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to just point you somewhere else, but there is a section in the FME help documents that has far more info than I could write here:

http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Workbench/Workbench/coordinate_sys_custom_about.htm

Also, there are a number of articles in the FME Knowledge Centre about custom coordinate systems:

https://knowledge.safe.com/search.html?f=&type=kbentry&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=custom+coordinate+system

I don't see any indication that EPSG:3765 is planned to be added in the near future. If you want it added I suggest you contact the [Safe support team](http://support.safe.com) and ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

We have added an interactive web page that makes defining new coordinate systems for FME a lot easier. You can find it at [fme.ly/coordsys](http://fme.ly/coordsys).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Who is "We"?  As per [help/behavior] please disclose your affiliation if promoting your own product in an answer.